# Grouping using Map and Reduce

Tags: couchdb, mapreduce

I have some documents with a "status" field of "Green", "Red", "Amber".

I'm sure it's possible to use MapReduce to produce a grouped response containing three keys (one for each status), each with a value containing an array of all the documents with that key. However, I'm struggling on how to use re(reduce) functions.

Map function:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.status, doc);
}
```

Reduce function: ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you will not use a reduce function to obtain your list of documents. A reduce is meant to take a list, and reduce it to a single value. In fact, there is an upper limit to the size of a reduce value anyways, and using entire documents will trigger a `reduce_overflow` error. Examples of reduces are counts, sums, averages, etc. Stick with the map query, and you will have your values collated and sorted by the `status` value.

On another, possibly unrelated note, I would not emit the document with your view. You can just use the `include_docs` view query parameter, and achieve the same effect, while saving disk-space in the process. The trade-off is that internally the doc will have to be retrieved one-by-one. (but since they're indexed already by `_id` anyways, it's usually a negligible difference.

Comment: +1. CouchDB likes tall lists, not fat lists. You already *do* have an array of "Green" documents if you query `?reduce=false&key="Green"`. That will give you an array of the documents (plus some other data which you can ignore, or remove with a _list function).

Comment: ?include_docs=true introduces a race condition where the doc can change in between the time that Couch reads the view row from disk, and when it goes back to read the document from disk. The doc can change in that brief time. But I think the vast majority of applications have *much* bigger things to worry about.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a problem that reduce is intended to solve; reduce in CouchDB is for aggregation.

If I understand you correctly, you want this;

Map:

```
function(doc) {
  for (var i in doc.status) {
    emit(doc.status[i], null);
  }
}
```

You can then find all docs of status Green with;

```
/_design/foo/_view/bar?key="Green"&include_docs=true
```

This will return a list of all docs with that status. If you wish to find docs of more than one status in a single query, then use http POST with a body of this form;

```
{"keys":["Green", "Red"]}
```

HTH,
B.